# Como gerar números aleatórios no prompt de comando?

Tags: windows, batch, random

Tenho um arquivo em `.cmd` e preciso que ele gere números aleatórios com 10 algoritmos. Como por exemplo *9006100001* e *1579970319* gerados aleatoriamente.

Atualmente tenho a seguinte função gerando números aleatórios com base no *time*, do sistema.

```
setlocal 
for /f "skip=8 tokens=2,3,4,5,6,7,8 delims=: " %%D in ('robocopy /l * \ \ /ns /nc /ndl /nfl /np /njh /XF * /XD *') do (
 set "dow=%%D"
 set "month=%%E"
 set "day=%%F"
 set "HH=%%G"
 set "MM=%%H"
 set "SS=%%I"
 set "year=%%J"
)
```

Dessa função, utilizo apenas o `%SS%`, é o mais perto que consegui do que quero até agora, como eu poderia criar algo semelhante para gerar números aleatórios?

Se possível, poderiam incluir uma variação disso com caracteres alfanuméricos*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma outra alternativa é criar um alfabeto com os caracteres que você quer gerar, num laço [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) você usa o [`random`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-random.html) para obter aleatoriamente um índice e acessa o valor de um `array`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "alfabeto=0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"

set "tamanho=0"
set "resultado="

REM Cria um array com os elementos
for %%a in (%alfabeto%) do (
    set "!tamanho!=%%a"
    set /a "tamanho+=1"
)

REM Retorna 10 caracteres aleatórios
for /L %%G in (1 1 10) do (
    set /a "indice=!random! %% tamanho"
    for %%b in (!indice!) do set "resultado=!resultado!!%%b!"
)

echo %resultado%
endlocal
```

---

> Se possível, poderiam incluir uma variação disso com caracteres alfanuméricos?

Usando o exemplo acima, inclua os caracteres no alfabeto:

```
set "alfabeto=a b c d f g h i j k l m n p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
```

Comment: Ótima resposta, aceitando porque atendeu a todos os requisitos da pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Com sua função que já está gerando numeros aleatórios, pegue o resultado e multiplique por um numero grande, e enquanto este número não passar de 10 algarismos, continue multiplicando.
EX:

```
@echo off
mode 76,30
color 9f
title Gerador de numeros aleatorios com mais de 10 algarimos
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:MAIN
cls 
echo.
echo Gerador de numeros aleatorios.
echo.
set start=s
set /p start=Iniciar(s/n):
if %start% equ s call :gerar && goto multiplicar
if not %start% equ s goto MAIN
goto MAIN

:gerar
set gerar=%random%

:multiplicar
set /A gerar=%gerar%*9876
if not %gerar% gtr 999999999 goto multiplicar
if %gerar% gtr 999999999 goto n_gerado

:n_gerado
echo.
echo nº gerado: %gerar%
pause>nul
goto MAIN
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: É uma opção, mas o uso do _loop_ é algo que pretendo evitar se puder, meu script é de execução continua, ou seja, essa função é usada a cada **x** segundos. De qualquer modo obrigado.